# What is this manga with a lion on its cover?

Tags: merchandise

I saw this manga in a local bookstore but its name was completely in Hapanese. I'm curious about it and want to google it except for the fact that I dont know what the name even is. Has anyone seen it before, or can anyone tell what the title says?

[image: cover]

Comment: http://myanimelist.net/manga/76563/Jasmin

Answer (score 5):

This is volume 1 of「ヤスミーン」(*Yasumiin*), written as "*Jasmin*" in English letters, authored by the *mangaka* [Hatake Yui](https://twitter.com/hata_yui) (畑 優以). It is published by Shuueisha (株式会社集英社) under its Young Jump Comics (ヤングジャンプコミックス) line.

It is [available to read for free online](http://www.s-manga.net/omf/omf_978-4-08-890116-9.html) as an e-book on Shuueisha's official website.